# Type parametrization and inheritance in Scala

Tags: scala, inheritance, type-parameter

I have Scala code following the pattern below.

```
class T

class A1[S <: T](private val arg1: String, private val arg2: S)
class A2[S <: T](private val arg1: String, private val arg2: S)
  extends A1[S]
class A3[S <: T](private val arg1: String, private val arg2: S)
  extends A2[S]
```

etc.

I am hoping that there is some way to shorten the above code because there is a lot of repetition here. I would like subclasses of `A1` to implicitly have the type parametrization `[S <: T]` and the constructor `(private val arg1: String, private val arg2: S)`. Is there any way to accomplish this, or is it necessary to repeat this text for every subclass I define?

Answer (score 0):

Can you replace `A1`, `A2`, and `A3` with a single `AImpl`?

```
sealed trait Condition
case object One   extends Condition
case object Two   extends Condition
case object Three extends Condition

sealed trait AParent[A]
case class AImpl[A, B <: A](private val arg1: String, 
                            private val arg2: B, 
                            c: Condition) extends AParent[A]
```

Comment: Unfortunately no. It's important that `Ai` is a subclass of `A(i-1)`

Comment: I just edited my answer, which had failed to specify `arg2` to be a sub-type of `AParent`. Is this new answer still not sufficient for what you need?

Comment: hi @AlexGrounds - my edited answer doesn't meet your needs either?